# How to write a unit test for a video library?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, widget, video-library

I have written a video library in C++. It contains a variety of graphical widgets such as text editor, list box, button, etc.

I have also written a simple unit testing framework that suits my needs for every other library. However, I can't figure out a way to unit test a widget without requiring visual inspection and user interaction. Is it possible?

I work in an environment where 3rd party libraries aren't an option.

Comment: If you have a GUI, which can be controlled by a script, you might be able to write tests. Otherwise, I fear not.

Comment: Hmm, I think I could write tests that simulate keypresses or mouse activity, but the visual inspection requirement seems unavoidable.